# How do I call or update a state of another component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I already know all the theory of React Native unidirectional and things like that, what I would want is a piece of code that shows how can you update a state of another component.

I have tried something this sample:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // Bind the this context to the handler function
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);

    // Set some state
    this.state = {
        messageShown: false
    };
}

// This method will be sent to the child component
handler() {
    this.setState({
        messageShown: true
    });
}

// Render the child component and set the action property with the handler as value
render() {
    return <Child action={this.handler} />
}
```

}

```
class Child extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {/* The button will execute the handler function set by the parent component */}
            <Button onClick={this.props.action} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

It just does not seem to work for me. Pressing Button nothing seems to fire or do anything!

Also if I add the child component within the Parent render() then the child UI shows on my parent which I dont want to... How to just update Parent!

Comment: Running the exact code you have provided here works for me. I see the value of `messageShown` in the `Parent` component switching to `true` when I click the button.

Comment: What are you doing to try and validate whether or not it is working? Maybe that is where the problem is.

Comment: @casieber it seems to work for me this sample , but when I try to adapt this technique into my real app, for some reason the button on Press does not fire the function within the parent. I am using StackNavigator , DrawerNavigator and adding the childs as:  Mood: {
                screen: Scr1,
                navigationOptions: {
                    title: 'Hello'
                }
            },

Comment: Do you want to rewrite the question with some code that reproduces the error?

Comment: @stone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292659/unable-to-call-or-update-state-of-another-component-react-native